# Graph processing using GraphX in Apache Spark + big data

Tags: scala, graph, vertex

I have created a Graph using node and edges data in Spark application. Now, I want to come up with the adjacency list for the created graph. How can I achieve this ?

I have written following code to read csv files for node and edge data and creating the Graph.

```
val grapha = sc.textFile("graph.csv")
val getgdata = grapha.map(line=>line.split(","))  
val node1 = getgdata.map(line=>(line(3).toLong,(line(0)))).distinct  
val node2 = getgdata.map(line=>(line(4).toLong,(line(1)))).distinct 

// This is node list of a graph.
val nodes = node1.union(node2).distinct  

//This is edge list.
val routes = getgdata.map(line=> 
 (Edge(line(3).toLong,line(4).toLong,line(2)))).distinct    

// now create graph using Graph library
val graphx = Graph(nodes,routes)
```

Now I need to see adjacency list for each node from this graph. How can I do it using scala?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I am assuming that your `graph.csv` looks like following,

```
node_1, node_2, node_1_relation_node_2, 1, 2
node_1, node_3, node_1_relation_node_3, 1, 3
node_2, node_3, node_2_relation_node_3, 2, 3
```

Now, you can read this into an RDD as follows,

```
val graphData = sc.textFile("graph.csv").map(line => line.split(","))
```

Now, you to create your graph you need two things,

RDD of Vertices,

```
val verticesRdd = graphData.flatMap(line => List(
    (line(3), line(0)),
    (line(4), line(1))
  )).distinct
```

RDD of Edges,

```
val edgesRdd = graphData.map(line => Edge(line(3), line(4), line(2))).distinct
```

Now, you can create your graph as,

```
val graph = Graph(verticesRdd, edgesRdd)
```

But if you just need adjacency list, you can obtain it just from the `graphData` as following,

```
val adjacencyRdd = graphData
  .flatMap(line => {
    val v1 = line(3).toLong
    val v2 = line(4).toLong
    List(
      (v1, v2),
      (v2, v1)
    )
  )
  .aggregateByKey(Set.empty[Long])(
    { case (adjacencySet, vertexId) => adjacencySet + vertexId }
    { case (adjacencySet1, adjacencySet2) => adjacencySet1 ++ adjacencySet2 }
  )
  .map({ case (vertexId, adjacencySet) => (vertextId, adjacencySet.toList) })
```

Comment: Hi Sarvesh , Thanks for your code.Let me clarifying more.  graph data row contains Node1, Node 2, Edge Weight, Node 1 Weight, Node 2Weight . I created graph successfully and I have another data list where each row contains Node1, Node 2,Class Label . Now I have to check these nodes in my graph and find common neighbors of each node and find similarity. I can't run your code for adjacency list.

Comment: Adjust the above code for your input files. node RDD for Graph needs vertexIds and not vertex weights.

Comment: Finally I got the solution, here is the link https://bigdatadatascience.blogspot.com/